# The "wind" force field and the "turbulence" force field do not work on the particle system. why?

Tags: particles, physics, force-fields

The object has grass on it, and I want to make it flow, but when I add a wind force field it does not show any effect, or I want to make realistic grass that flows like real grass, but nothing was happening in physics.

Comment: I'm not sure it will work as you want if your particle is an object, but anyway first you need to make sure that the Hair Dynamics option is enabled. But maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Yes, I have made my grass with objects and I also enabled the hair dynamic option, but it hasn't changed as before

Comment: so maybe share your file (only the grass + forcefield)?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the physics tab and activate collision. Now you will got the result that you want.

Comment: activate Collision for which object? Could you please give a bit more details?